# Relations between 4 tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 tables event, group, category, judoka. Event has many groups, group has many categories and category has many judokas. So how can i realize this? I tried to create pivot tables event_group, group_category, category_judoka, but when I put judokas to category they are in all events not just in one. I have many to many relations between all tables. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble figuring out the query here, can you post the code for the relationships and the actual query you are trying to run?

Comment: "Event has many groups, group has many categories and category has many judokas." based on this.. you don't need pivot table. why is it many to many situation?

Comment: Because I can create many events where can be same groups but different judokas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, i found a solution. Just created pivot table with 3 values category_id, event_id and judoka_id. Attached values like this: `$categoryf->events()->attach($categoryf->id, ['event_id' => $event->id, 'judoka_id' => $judokas->id]);`

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the reverse of relation for us to know how to best answer that but here is what You can Do it you just need a 1 to n relation ship between them all :
here in your Event model :

```
public function group(){
return $this->hasMany(Group::class);
}
```

and in your Group model :

```
 public function category(){
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }
```

and in your Category Model :

```
public function judokas(){
        return $this->hasMany(Judokas::class);
}
```

and consider to put a modelname_id in your related table so for example in your event model you need a column like :

```
group_id
```

and in your Group model you need a column like :

```
category_id
```

and in Your Category model you need a column like :

```
jukodas_id
```

and now you can access all the relation by nestest relationships so for example in your controller you can use thew like below :

```
 $data = Event::with('Group', 'category.judokas');
```

here you can get the nested relationship which is the category relation inside the judokas .
i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but 
based on your description you should have this relations :

1. events has many categories
2. events has many judokas
3. groups has many judokas

when you add judoka to cateory you should sync this relations :

```
category->events()->judokas()
category->groups()->judokas()
```

and access them like this:

```
event->judokas()
group->judokas()
```